# Equivalent of a yield take Redux Saga in Redux thunks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I'm currently converting the sagas in the code base to thunks.

I know that Sagas' specific functions such `yield put`, `yield call` have a "direct translation" to thunks `dispatch(...)` and `await fn...`.

I came across `yield take` which from what I understand takes a set of actions included in the store and instructs the middleware to wait for one of those specified actions from the store and the result is an action object that gets dispatched?

What would be the "equivalent" if using Redux thunks?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't listen for actions in thunks, without custom middleware. The maintainers of redux & redux-toolikt are working on an api for RTK that should do something like that though https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sagas example:

```
export function* sample() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(api.sample)
        yield put(setData(response.data))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(setError(error))
    }
}

export function* sampleSaga() {
yield takeEvery( YOUR_TYPE, sample)
```

}

if you wanna change it to redux thunk , you can do it:

```
 export function sample(){
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
     api.sample()
     .then((response)=> dispatch(setData(response.data)))
     .catch(error => Promise.reject(error))
  }
 }
```

Comment: where does yield take come into play here?

Comment: generator function behaves like a loop, wehn you use yield , it will stop, so for running next yield method, you use next method, you can use takeEvery method to run all the yield methods, in thunk we dont have sth like this, then you dont need any alternative for take method

Comment: Alternatively, a direct equivalent would look more like:


    export const sample = () => async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = api.sample()
            dispatch(setData(response.data)))
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(setError(error)))
        }
    }